# How to rotate pictures in iOS 8?

Tags: iphone, photos, ios, photos.app

Updated to iOS 8 some time ago, now I have to rotate a picture and the "rotate" option is gone. Where is the functionality located?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to the photo in Photos, tap **Edit**, then tap the **Crop** button to show the **Rotate** button.

Tapping the Crop button is what's new here as in iOS 7 this wasn't required.

Comment: Note that iOS 8 automatically tries to straighten the image. You may need to tap the reset button first, and then rotate the image.